# Image not stretching in ios 7.1 but working perfectly in 7.0 and 8.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7.1

Image is not stretching while using the method

```
_bubbleView.image=[[UIImage imageNamed:@"bubblebg"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(40.0f, 19.0f, 11.0f, 10.0f) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch]
```

only in iOS 7.1. But this method works perfectly in iOS 7.0,8.0 and 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember have an issue with tab bar icons and edge insets of varying sizes in 7.1, might be an issue here as well.

For your insets, try making the top/bottom & left/right be equal and see if you still have the issue. `UIEdgeInsetsMake(11.0f, 19.0f, 11.0f, 19.0f)`